# Kill a batch file containing the python script within

Tags: python, batch-file, kill

I have a problem. I need to kill the batch file using the python script residing within the same batch file. The batch file has **abc.py** script as the first one along with other scripts. So I need to kill the batch file so that others don't get executed. Here is what I have tried:

```py
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
     if proc.name() == "python.exe" and len(proc.cmdline()) > 1 and 
         "abc.py" in proc.cmdline()[1]:
    proc.terminate()
```

But this only kills the python script, not the batch file. Tried killing the pid  with the same effect.

```py
os.system("taskkill /F /PID " + str(os.getpid()))
```

**Edit 1**
The script checks for existence of another running script and then needs to terminate itself.

Comment: Not a solution, but an alternative. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907163/how-can-i-stop-a-programs-execution-with-python .

Comment: Try using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978013/need-to-find-which-program-called-the-python-script or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728330/how-to-get-processs-grandparent-id/4229596 .

Comment: sys.exit() terminates abc.py but not the others. I need to kill the batch file.

Comment: I need to kill the batch file programatically. So cannot use process explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking to kill whoever your parent is, that's easy: just use [`os.getppid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getppid) instead of `os.getpid()`:

```
os.system("taskkill /F /PID " + str(os.getppid()))
```

Of course it's better to use `subprocess` instead of `os.system` for all the usual reasons, like getting a useful error if it fails:

```
subprocess.run(['taskkill', '/F', '/PID', str(os.getppid())])
```

Or, even better, don't use `taskkill`, just [`kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) it directly. This also gives you the option of using a nicer [Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) kill instead of a hard kill, if preferred:

```
os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
```

---

If you're using Python 2.7, `getppid` doesn't work on Windows; that was only added in 3.2. (And I think the same is true for `os.kill`, and definitely for `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`.)

Since you're already apparently amenable to using `psutil`, you can use that.

There's no need to search through every process on the system to find yourself, just construct a default [`Process`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process). And you can go from any process to its parent with [`parent`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.parent). And then you can use the [`kill`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.kill) or [`terminate`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.terminate)

```
proc = psutil.Process().parent()
proc.kill()
```

---

All of the above, except using `CTRL_C_EVENT` or `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` instead of a standard signal), have the nice advantage of being cross-platform—you can run the same script on Linux or macOS or whatever and it'll kill the shell script that ran it.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation. I wanted  a programmatic solution. It works!!

Comment: @MallikKumar One thing: this will kill _whoever_ its parent is. If, say, you accidentally run this program from your IDE, it'll kill your IDE. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file will need to check whether the last command succeeded and exit if it didn't.

See [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error)

Comment: Summarize the link here

Comment: @user202729 ..try except sys.exit()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426045/difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-python

Comment: @user202729 I know the difference between exit(0) and exit(1)